# Declare (automatically) variables in vba

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to declare (automatically) variables in vba and with increasing number?
I have to Dim 50 variables,  like Var1  till  Var50
Is it possible with vba code

All my efforts (for next  with concatenate) didn't work

The result should be;

Dim Var1 as integer
Dim Var2 as integer
.
.
Dim Var50 as integer

Comment: You want to use an array.  `Dim Var(1 ro 50) as integer` then you can use it like `Var(1) = 23` and so forth.

Comment: For the love of everything that is good in this world, please, don't do this. **Use meaningful names**, and if you need 50 values of `SomeMeaningfulName`, then use an array, like `SomeMeaningfulName(0 To 49) As Integer`. Don't call it `Var`, give it a name that tells whoever is maintaining that code (future you?) what these values are used for. If they're completely unrelated, then make a `Type` and give each one a meaningful name. And then thank yourself later (e.g. *was the column width of Sheet4!$A:$F stored in var23 or var47 again?*)

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
Dim Var(1 to 50) as integer
```

Then you can set values for each like so

```
Var(1) = 1
Var(2) = 2
Var(3) = 3
Var(4) = 4
Var(5) = 5
Var(6) = 6
Var(7) = 7
Var(8) = 8
Var(9) = 9
Var(10) = 10
Var(11) = 11
Var(12) = 12
Var(13) = 13
Var(14) = 14
Var(15) = 15
Var(16) = 16
Var(17) = 17
Var(18) = 18
Var(19) = 19
Var(20) = 20
Var(21) = 21
Var(22) = 22
Var(23) = 23
Var(24) = 24
Var(25) = 25
Var(26) = 26
Var(27) = 27
Var(28) = 28
Var(29) = 29
Var(30) = 30
Var(31) = 31
Var(32) = 32
Var(33) = 33
Var(34) = 34
Var(35) = 35
Var(36) = 36
Var(37) = 37
Var(38) = 38
Var(39) = 39
Var(40) = 40
Var(41) = 41
Var(42) = 42
Var(43) = 43
Var(44) = 44
Var(45) = 45
Var(46) = 46
Var(47) = 47
Var(48) = 48
Var(49) = 49
Var(50) = 50
```

Comment: Arrays declared with an implicit lower bound would be zero-based unless there's `Option Base 1` specified, which makes explicit boundaries `(1 To 50)` potentially confusing if `Option Base 1` *isn't* specified.

Comment: And please use a loop to assign those!

Comment: Not sure if you are serious but `For x = 1 to 50: Var(x) = x: Next x`

Comment: Thanks! Yep definitely am serious... never too late to stop learning :)